# Android Custom View to Activity communication

Tags: android, events, custom-controls, handler

I have a custom control/view that observes the direction of a gesture within its bounds. I would like to send a different message back to the Activity hosting the View depending on the direction of the gesture. I'm having a hard time determine what the right way to do this is. I would think I could raise a custom event in the control and then stick a listener on the control in the activity, but I cannot find any information on custom events in Android. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Boy, just a little bit more digging and I wouldn't have had to ask the question. For those who come this way wondering the same thing, though, I found this article did exactly what I was looking for: 
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/custom-view-horizontalslider

Comment: Glad you found the solution! However, could you mark this as accepted? It removes this question from the list of open issues, and lets people searching through questions know right away that there's a solution to be found here.

Comment: I'd love to, but I can't mark my own answer as accepted until 48 hours after I posted the original question.

Comment: doesn't that solution create a circular reference between activity and view? (which poses a memory leak problem)